# VS Code: Não é possível inicializar o dispositivo PRN (Python 3..7.2)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

Olá!
Estou com um problema na configuração do Python no VS Code.
Quando executa o comando `print('Olá Mundo!')`, o terminal retorna:

> Não é possível inicializar o dispositivo PRN.

A versão do VS Code é: 
**1.30.2 (user setup)**

No path o caminho está correto.
Não sei o que está causando esse erro.

Desde já agradeço...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eu tive esse mesmo problema quando acidentalmente digitei "impressão program.py "em vez de"python program.py ". A mensagem de erro vem do programa de linha de comando do Windows chamado print.

Comment: Provavelmente seja coincidencia, mas sua resposta parece uma tradução [dessa aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26721404/2879341), sendo ou não sendo sugiro que complemente a resposta dando a mesma sugestão que autor da resposta em inglês deu, e tb troque a frase "impressão program.py", por "print program.py" (foi isso q me chamou a atenção para pesquisar, muuuito estranho) :-)

Comment: Tinha reparado isso. Mas nao fui eu que escrevi essa menção. Esse erro aparece no terminal fo vs code. Deve ser um erro simples, mas não consigo saber onde está

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver no Windows, tem que chamar o Python primeiro para ele funcionar:

- 1- feche seu prompt aberto (caso estiver)
- 2- abra novamente e só escreva `Python`
- 3- escreva novamente `print('Olá Mundo!')`
  e isso irá funcionar!